# Load a full list of IDs from DB or perform one record at a time ? What's best?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, database-performance

I migrate a custom made web site to WordPress and first I have to migrate the data from the previous web site, and then, every day I have to perform some data insertion using an API.

The data I like to insert, comes with a unique ID, representing a single football game.

In order to avoid inserting the same game multiple times, I made a db table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `ss_highlight_ids` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `highlight_id` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000000000',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `highlight_id_UNIQUE` (`highlight_id`),
    KEY `highlight_id_INDEX` (`highlight_id`) COMMENT 'Contains a list with all the highlight IDs. This is used as index, and dissalow the creation of double records.'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2967 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and when I try to insert a new record in my WordPress db, I first like to lookup this table, to see if the ID already exists.

The question now :)

What's preferable ? To load all the IDs using a single SQL query, and then use plain PHP to check if the current game ID exists, or is it better to query the DB for any single row I insert ?

I know that MySQL Queries are resource expensive, but from the other side, currently I have about 3k records in this table, and this will move over 30 - 40k in the next few year, so I don't know if it's a good practice to load all of those records in PHP ?

What is your opinion / suggestion ?

**UPDATE #1**

I just found that my table has 272KiB size with 2966 row. This means that in the near feature it seems that will have a size of about ~8000KiB+ size, and going on.

**UPDATE #2**

Maybe I have not make it too clear. For first insertion, I have to itterate a CSV file with about 12K records, and after the CSV insertion every day I will insert about 100 - 200 records. All of those records requiring a lookup in the table with the IDs.

So the excact question is, is it better to create a 12K queries in MySQL at CSV insertion and then about 100 - 200 MySQL Queries every day, or just load the IDs in server memory, and use PHP for the lookup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table has a column `id` which is auto_increment, what that means is there is no need to insert anything in that column. It will fill it itself.

Comment: This is not a big deal, I can remove it. The question is related to what is better for performance

Comment: Then, what you can do is make a select statement with a where clause where you check if the id exists, if not do your thing, if yes, break. Something like that, no need to load the whole table and check every single row with php when you can do it with a single sql query. EDIT: its not going to be slow if you do it like that, its going to get slow if you use php. I will give you an example SELECT highlight_id FROM table WHERE highlight_id = :id. With this you can check if the id exists.

Comment: Again, seems like you don't understand the question. Maybe I didn't explain it right, I will fix my explaination again. The think is that every day I will insert about 100 records in my DB, meaning I have to do about  100 loopup in the table with the IDs. From prespective of performance is it ok to create 100 Queries in DB or it's better to load all records at once and use the PHP for the lookup ?

Comment: Its better to use only a single query for every row you try to insert. It's not a problem for the performance. If you get only 30-40k in a few years its nothing. You have an index which is going to even speed things up. You need to get worried when your rows reach 1-2mil+. For a few thousands its not going to be a big deal on the db. Don't use php.

Answer (score 1):

`highlight_id` is `UNIQUE`, so it may as well be the `PRIMARY KEY`; get rid if `id`.

A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key is an `INDEX`.  So this is redundant:

```
KEY `highlight_id_INDEX` (`highlight_id`)
```

Back to your question...  SQL is *designed* to do things in batches.  Don't defeat that by doing things one row at a time.

How can the table be 272KiB size if it has only two columns and 2966 rows?  If there are more columns in the table; show them.  There are often good clues of what you are doing, and how to make it more efficient.

2966 rows is 'trivial'; you will have to look closely to see performance differences.

Loading from CSV...

If this is a replacement, use LOAD DATA, building a new table, then RENAME to put it into place.  One CREATE, one LOAD, one RENAME, one DROP.  Much more efficient than 100 queries of any kind.

If the CSV is updates/inserts, LOAD into a temp table, then do `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` to perform the updates/inserts into the real table.  One CREATE, one LOAD, one IODKU.  Much more efficient than 100 queries of any kind.

If the CSV is something else, please elaborate.